# Getting the average value and the sum of all values in a user-inputed array?

Tags: java, arrays, while-loop, sum, average

I need to write an application which can store 10 000 user-inputed values, in an array, and that can return the sum of all values and the average of all values. The input must be stopped if the user writes the number "0". There are some conditions that need to be fulfilled:

1. The values needs to be stored in an array
2. The users input data must be inside a while-loop
3. The analysis (the math, so to speak), must be done after the user-input is done.
4. The application is not allowed to loop any empty elements.

This is a extra assignment I got in class today.

So far I've written this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Ovning_54 {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            int[] list;
            list = new int[10000];
            int sum = 0;
            int avr = 0;
            int x = 0;
            int number;

            System.out.print("Add number " + (x + 1) + ": ");
            number = input.nextInt();

            while (x <= list.length && (number != 0 || x == 0)) {
                 list[x] = number;
                 x++;
                 System.out.print("Add number " + (x + 1) + ": ");
                 number = input.nextInt();
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
                 sum += list[i];
                 avr = sum / x;
            }

            System.out.println("The sum of all values are: " + sum);
            System.out.println("The average value of the numbers are: " + avr);
          }

    }
```

I think I've solved it! Seems to be running correctly and I get no error messages what so ever. I'm still wondering if that violates condition #1. If not, is there a way around it?

Comment: `The analysis (the math, so to speak), must be done after the user-input is done.` Awhh, the most elegant solution would calculate it along the way

Comment: @ Cruncher. Yes, we had that in class. How to calculate within the while-loop. But this is a little bit trickier.

Comment: you were really close! The biggest problem here is that you were losing how many elements you entered, which is very important to calculating average(and avoiding looping any empty elements).

Comment: I think I've solved it now!

Comment: You should either accept an answer, or post your own answer with the solution and accept that.

Comment: I will as soon as I get the "correct" answer from the teacher. The only question mark in this code is the first number = input.nextInt(); . I'm still wondering if that violates condition #1. If not, is there a way around it?

Comment: `The values needs to be stored in an array` Your values do get stored in an array, even if they were stored somewhere else first.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I meant condition 2. I understand that pretty much everything is stored in the array within the while-loop. But not the first input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace  your  `while (x <= list.length)` with this one.

```
while (x <= list.length && (number != 0 || x==0))
```

Replace your for loop

```
for(int i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
    sum += list[i];
}
```

with this one.

```
for(int i = 0; i < x; i++){
    sum += list[i];
}
```

Now your modified code look like below

```
    public static void main (String[] args){
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            int[] list;
            list = new int[10000];
            int sum = 0;
            int avr = 0;
            int x = 0;
            int number;

            while (x <= list.length && (number != 0 || x==0)){
                 System.out.print("Add number " + (x+1) + ": ");
                 number = input.nextInt();
                 list[x] = number;
                 x++;                     
            }

            for(int i = 0; i < x; i++){
                 sum += list[i];
            }

          }
```

Comment: How does this improve the code? What is the difference?

@ Cruncher. Got it!

Answer (score 2):

change

`x = list.length;` to `break;`

This will preserve your x, which is how many entries they made. Alternatively you could set another variable to x, then set x to list.length. I know some teachers tell students not to use break(which I still don't understand)

Then your for loop becomes:

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < x ; i++)
```

Then after the for loop, your average is sum/x.

EDIT: After giving a second look, it appears as though x may be 1 too big when you go to calculate average. You can fix this by either, using (x-1) in your calculation(less natural), or putting the break condition before the incrementation of x in your while loop(more natual).

Comment: We still haven't learned what break actually does, so I'm guessing I can't use it in this assignment.

Comment: @Dinco in that case, I would recommend putting `number = input.nextInt();` before your while loop, and as the last line in your while loop. Then add `&& number != 0` in the while condition. Then you can drop the if statement with the break all together.